Paypal checkout doesn't send PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED on purchase to my webhook
I'm trying to create a webhook to listen for paypal checkout purchases.
When user purchases some item paypal is supposed to send data to my server (all I need is an email)
I had created a nodejs webhook POST request using express.js and it does receive data only from webhook simulator multiple times, even when I only clicked it once (https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/webhooksSimulator)
Here's my source code:
app.post('/paypal-webhook', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Webhook event received')
    const rawBody = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    console.log(rawBody)
    const signature = req.headers['paypal-transmission-sig'];
    console.log(req.body)
   
    const verified = crypto.createHmac('sha256', paypalWebhookSecret)
        .update(rawBody)
        .digest('hex');

    if (signature === verified) {
        const event = req.body;

        // Check if the event is a payment sale completed event
        if (event.event_type === 'PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED') {
            console.log('Payment sale completed:', event);
            // Your course fulfillment logic here
        }

        res.status(200).send('Webhook received successfully.');
    } else {
        console.error('Webhook verification failed.');
        res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
    }
});

The issue I'm having is that on paypal checkout when user buys something it doesn't send anything to my webhook. It only sends data from webhooks simulator.

What integration are you using for PayPal Checkout? Have you subscribed to all events in http://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications for the same app/client-id ?
PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED is for subscription payments. Depending on your integration, the event name will be something else. Though if this is a basic v2/checkout/orders integration, you shouldn't have your code rely on webhooks (use the immediate server-side capture API response instead)

Yes, I did subscribe to all events and am using same app id.
Didn't know that it's for subscription payments, but still it should send that Webhook event has been received which it doesn't

you can add another webhook listener URL to http://webhook.site to test in parallel

if that doesn't shed light, update your question with the checkout code you're using and also an example capture response showing a recent capture ID that you haven't received a webhook for
